# No option of 'IIS Client Certificate Mapping Authentication' in windows features

Tags: iis, windows-8

How to install 'IIS Client Certificate Mapping Authentication' on windows feature.

Under: Internet Information Services >> World Wide Web Services >> Security

OS: win 8
IIS: 8.5

Image as shown Below
[image]

[image]

Comment: I assume you are using the Home Edition of Windows 8. Some more advanced features of IIS are not supported in Home.

Comment: @Peter Hahndorf: Thank You,  Yes, that might be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Home Edition of Windows 8 some of the more advanced features of IIS are not supported.

If you really need them, upgrade to Windows 8 Pro or user a server edition (free for evaluation for 180 days)